# How can we call the internal api which is hosted on same server application using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, security

I am trying to access the application api which is hosted under the same application which is secure (https).

I would like to call the API which is available inside the my application and provided by the third party framework.

Is there any way to call the service without protocol (https://localhost:XXXX). Due to some security restrictions, I can not pass host address which executing the request on local server.

Thank you

Comment: Any reason why you can't call the method directly, since it's same app.

Comment: I don't wanted to manipulate the implementation of third party. there are many apis provided by the third party framework. And i wanted to make it in a single call using paramters.